# ¿Instalar Certificado SSL en RedHat Secure Web Server?

Tags: php, servidor, ssl, certificado-ssl

Me pueden ayudar porfavor con este tema, Como realizar el proceso de la instalación del certificado SSL, Ya tengo las llaves necesarias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para instalar un Certificado SSL en RedHat Secure Web Server, tomando en cuenta que sabes manejar RedHat, por favor realiza los siguientes pasos:

1. Busca el certificado Intermedio CA y pegarlo en un bloc de notas,
   guardar el archivo como intermediate.crt.
2. La entidad certificadora le envia via email el certificado SSL,
   descargalo. Si el certificado se encuentra en el cuerpo del email,
   copiarlo y pegarlo en un bloc de notas. Guardar el archivo como
   public.crt.

   El texto del certificado debe mostrarse asi:

   –––––BEGIN CERTIFICATE–––––

   .......

   –––––END CERTIFICATE–––––
3. Agregar las siguientes directivas en el archivo
   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, dentro del Virtual Host. Recuerde que
   también necesitara el archivo que contiene su llave privada.

   SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/public.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/intermediate.crt
4. Reinicie su servidor RedHat.
5. Verifique la instalacion de su certificado SSL.

Suerte!